# ES6 / Meteor Singleton pattern with inheritance

Tags: javascript, inheritance, meteor, ecmascript-6

I have programmed a singleton using this blog:
http://amanvirk.me/singleton-classes-in-es6/

But I need a singleton on both client and server side.

That is, I have three programs: `common.js`

```
export class AppsManagerCommon {
  constructor(options) {
    // general options
    this.options = options;
    // list of registered apps
    this.apps = [];
  }
  registerApp(app) {
    a = this.apps.find(function (a) {return a.name === app.name;});
    console.log(a);
    this.apps.push(app);
  }
}
```

`client.js`

```
import { AppsManagerCommon } from 'common.js';
let instanceAppsManager = null;  // singleton pattern
export class AppsManager extends AppsManagerCommon {
  constructor(options) {
    if (!instanceAppsManager) {  // not yet instantiated
      super(options);
      instanceAppsManager = this;
    }
   return instanceAppsManager;
  }
}
```

`server.js` (identical to `client.js`)

```
import { AppsManagerCommon } from 'common.js';
let instanceAppsManager = null;  // singleton pattern
export class AppsManager extends AppsManagerCommon {
  constructor(options) {
    if (!instanceAppsManager) {  // not yet instantiated
      super(options);
      instanceAppsManager = this;
    }
   return instanceAppsManager;
  }
}
```

The singletoc can be used sucessfully with:

```
a = new AppsManager();
a.registerApp({name:'app1'});
```

but as soon as I do

```
b = new AppsManager(); // should be the same instance
```

I get an error:

```
ReferenceError: this hasn't been initialised - super() hasn't been called
    at BabelRuntime.possibleConstructorReturn (packages/babel-runtime.js:206:13)
```

I can more or less understand what the error means, but I have no clue how I could resolve the issue.

**EDIT 1**

NB The existence check in `registerApp` does not work, but is not a problem for now

Answer (score 0):

This is a working solution:

`common.js`

```
let instanceAppsManager = null;  // singleton pattern
export class AppsManagerCommon {
  constructor(options) {
    if (!instanceAppsManager) {  // not yet instantiated
      instanceAppsManager = this;
      // general options
      this.options = options;
      // list of registered apps
      this.apps = [];
    }
    return instanceAppsManager;
  }
  registerApp(app) {
    this.apps.push(app);
  }
}
```

`server.js` (identical to `client.js`)

```
import { AppCommon, AppsManagerCommon } from 'common.js';
export class AppsManager extends AppsManagerCommon {
  constructor(options) {
      super(options);
  }
}
```